# Can every letrec be replaced with letrec*?

Tags: scheme, language-lawyer, letrec, r7rs

For every 100% compliant R7RS-small program that does not rely on any implementation-specific or undefined behavior, is it true that every instance of `letrec` in the program can be replaced with `letrec*` without causing any change in behavior? In other words, is there any R7RS-small program where an appearance of `letrec` cannot be substituted with `letrec*`?

Answer (score 2):

I think that the answer is yes, it can, assuming that the form is not 'an error' in R7RS terminology (but see note at end).  In particular I think that if there's a form like

```
(letrec ((v1 <e1>) (v2 <e2>)) ...)
```

Then it must be possible to evaluate `<e2>` without referring to the value of `v1`, but that binding *does actually exist* when `<e2>` is evaluated: it is just an error to refer to it.  So in particular this is not allowed:

```
(let ((a 1)) (letrec ((a 2) (b a)) ...))
```

because the binding that the init for `b` refers to is that established by the `letrec`, *not* that established by the `let`, but it is not yet legal to refer to the value of that binding.

That being the case then if you simply replace `letrec` by `letrec*` then `<e2>` still will not refer to the value of `v1` and thus the results will be the same.

The converse is not true:

```
(letrec* ((a 1) (b a)) ...)
```

is fine, but you can't replace the `letrec*` by `letrec` there.

That being the case I'm unclear what useful purpose `letrec` serves (perhaps this is why Racket's `letrec` has the semantics of Scheme's `letrec*`).

---

**Note** an earlier version of this answer came to the opposite conclusion.  I am now not convinced I understand things well enough.

Comment: I tried the `letrec` example in MIT Scheme 11.2, Chibi 0.10.0, and Guile 3.0.7. MIT Scheme gives an error: `Unassigned variable: a`, Chibi returns `2`, and `guile --r7rs` returns `2`. Why do they not return `1` as you claim?

Comment: Yes, I am not sure my answer is right

Comment: @Flux: I think I was wrong: the new version of the answer comes to the opposite conclusion: yes, you can do this.  However I think we need a proper Scheme expert not an old lisp hacker who thinks they understand Scheme but perhaps does not like me.

Comment: "if you simply replace `letrec` by `letrec*` then `<e2>` still will not refer to the value of `v1` and thus the results will be the same." — Are you sure about this? `(letrec* ((a 2) (b a)) a)` returns `2`.

Comment: @Flux: Yes, that's right. `(letrec ((a 2) (b a)) ...)` is an error since the form `a` refers to the value of the binding of `a`: what I claim is that all `letrec` forms *which are not errors* can be replaced by `letrec*` forms.  If *all* `letrec` forms are blindly replaced by `letrec*` forms then some errors will become legal code, like this case.